# Apache rewrite third directory depth to first directory depth

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have resources for two websites located here...

```
localhost/index.php /* rewrite handler */
localhost/images/
localhost/scripts/
```

Then I have the two sites...

```
localhost/site1/
localhost/site2/
```

I want to rewrite...

```
localhost/site1/images/
localhost/site2/images/
localhost/site1/scripts/
localhost/site2/scripts/
```

...to...

```
localhost/images/site1/
localhost/images/site2/
localhost/scripts/site1/
localhost/scripts/site2/
```

Is there a way to make "site1" and "site2" a dynamic variable (so that I don't have to manually add an exception or rule if I add more sites in the future) that will rewrite in this manner?

This rule REWRITES the directory, I want to be able to access the files AS WELL, not just the index...

```
RewriteRule .*\/scripts\/$ scripts\/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For once the Apache documentation was useful!

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .*\/scripts(.+) scripts$1 [QSA]
```