# Apache match second directory after second slash, just not ^ begining of {REQUEST_URI}

Tags: apache

How do I match the SECOND directory of a request?

The first directory is completely irrelevant. So I can't use ^ since that matches the very beginning of {REQUEST_URI}. How do I tell Apache to start after the second /? Also I'm aware that / have to be escaped like /.

http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/

Comment: what do you have in your .htaccess?

Comment: you only have this? can you give me an example of URLS?

Comment: I've edited the post, I simply want to match against * the name of the directory is, regardless of what it is. I've seen bits like (.*) in example. Helpful Apache regex tutorials are nonexistent hence why I am having to ask this very specific question.

Comment: i am guessing here: but if you try `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]` then in your php file you will get: `Array ( [detail1] => directory1/directory2/ ) ` is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match `directory2` from your example:

```
.*\/(.*)\/$
```

Comment: Note that I can't see this being useful in itself unless you never plan on having a URL off of `directory2`.

Comment: This LOOKS like what I want. Where could I put a specific directory name in? e.g. .*\/(scripts)\/$ ?

Comment: Yes, this IS what I want. In example: RewriteRule .*\/scripts\/$ scripts\/$1 [L]

The point is to reuse files for multiple sites that are alike. Haf, if you post this on the following page I'll accept the answer there TOO! :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253779/apache-rewrite-third-directory-depth-to-first-directory-depth

Comment: Okay, this answers the first HALF of what I asked in the other question, you may be able to understand what I'm doing there now that you see the working code to get half way there. Sometimes it's best to break things down to smaller parts.